# In JQuery how do I select the correct textarea next to a button in the DOM?

Tags: jquery, html

I have created some code to select the textarea next to the button when it's clicked. There are going to be multiple of these on the page using the same class names.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="iframe-con bannerone-con"> </div>
<div class="hidden-code">
  <textarea class="copytxt"><?php echo file_get_contents(get_template_directory_uri().'/HTML-banner-sizes/970x250.php');//reads in file contents for the banner ?></textarea>
  <button class="clickme">Copy to clipboard</button>
</div>
<div class="iframe-con bannertwo-con"> </div>
<div class="hidden-code">
  <textarea class="copytxt"><?php echo file_get_contents(get_template_directory_uri().'/HTML-banner-sizes/728x90.php');//reads in file contents for the banner ?></textarea>
  <button class="clickme">Copy to clipboard</button>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(".clickme", this).click(function(){   
$('.copytxt').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

When you click on the button it just selects the last textarea. I know the jQuery code isn't right. I just want to make it so that when you press a button the element (textarea) is selected.

As I mentioned there will be more than two, I just thought it would be easier to understand if I just did two for now.

I've tried to have a look around the net, but can't find any example of what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Textarea `.copytxt` is previous sibling element of clicked button. You can use `.prev()` to traverse to immediate previous sibling element :

```
$(".clickme", this).click(function(){
   $(this).prev().select();
   document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

or traverse to closest parent div and then find element `.copytxt` in it:

```
$(".clickme", this).click(function(){
   $(this).closest('.hidden-code').find('.copytxt').select();
   document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

Comment: Nice one :) I knew it wasn't hard, just got a bit lost in the pages :/